# upgrading the core of a distro

Tags: upgrade, custom-distributions

If we have a **distro (A)** based on a **distro (B)**, and the **distro (B)** get un upgrade (it becames **B.01**) can we have un upgrade to the (**A**) distro to make it based on (**B.01**)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is possible. Here is a [community tutorial on Linux Mint](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/62) about doing so .

The caveat is that you may have problems depending on the level of customization you had, as well as package conflicts and other such problems. The comments on those articles suggest that the procedure mostly works, with some known definite issues.

The procedure, in this case, is simply to update entries in `/etc/apt/sources.list` to use the newer release (perhaps from a newer version of the derived distro), and run:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Oddly enough, the tutorial lists `sudo apt-get upgrade` as a step again after the `dist-upgrade` (to what end I do not know).

This really depends on how much customization the derivative does. For example, Ubuntu is often said to be based on Debian, but there is only a loose correlation or connection between Ubuntu and Debian releases.

Comment: thank you but i don't think that is what i really want to do. what i want to say is ,for exemple, we have mint 12 that is based on ubuntu 12 and we want to upgrade it to ubuntu 14 so we get mint 12 based on ubuntu 14 . is it possible ?

Comment: @zguell that is very close to what the tutorial does. In the tutorial, you add the source for the new version of Mint as well, where as you could try without adding Mint's new sources and only Ubuntu's. Whether it will actually work, I don't know. I can't find any experiments on the net.

Comment: yes it works I'm downloading now a tons of dependency . thanks man :)

Comment: @zguell thats too early to say it works. You'll likely face a lot of problems soon.

Comment: you'r right man, i fisrt had a lot of reboots and repeating the apt-get upgrade tons of time and finally i boot to a black screen (AMD Radeon problem) and now i'm using it with a crappy graphics and duplicate programs